# Loop 10000 times a json in a file

Tags: loops, batch-file

here is a array of json, how can i loop the json  10000 times in a separate file , is there any possible way to print it in a separte file

```
pets=[{a:"one b:"two"},{c:"three",d:"four"}];
```

The output should be in

```
pets=[{a:"one b:"two"},{c:"three",d:"four"},{a:"one b:"two"},{c:"three",d:"four"},{a:"one b:"two"},{c:"three",d:"four"},...........];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's an 8191-character limit for batch and command console commands, you basically have to append to the output file on each loop iteration.  But if you surround the loop in parentheses and redirect the output of that entire parenthetical code block to your outfile, then you don't have to reopen the file 10,000 times for appending.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "repeat={a:"one",b:"two"},{c:"three",d:"four"}"

>output.json (
    set /P "=pets=[%repeat%" <NUL
    for /L %%I in (1,1,9999) do set /P "=,%repeat%" <NUL
    set /P "=];" <NUL
)
```

Comment: I should also mention that `set /P "=string here" <NUL` behaves the same as `echo string here` but without the trailing line break.